# Storing ScheduledFuture in Class Variable in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am currently attempting to initiate a scheduled task in Kotlin using a ScheduledExecutorService, then store a reference to its ScheduledFuture on the class, so I can cancel the task later if need be with another function.

```
companion object {

        val submitPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
        var taskHandle : ??? // What type do I make this?

        val newTask= object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                foo()
            }
        }
      
        fun onStatusChange(connected : Boolean) {
            if(connected) {
                    taskHandle = submitPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(newTask, msUpdateRate, msUpdateRate, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                }
            } else { 
                taskHandle.cancel(true) // Cancel the task
            }
        }
}
```

I know the `scheduleWithFixedDelay` function returns a `ScheduledTask<?>`, but in the Kotlin variable, Android Studio says it is of type `ScheduledTask<*>`, which I can't store. How do I store that result as a variable on the companion object so I can call `cancel()` on it later?

Anything I tried so far throws a syntax error for type mismatch. Should I be casting the result to a `ScheduledTask<Unit>`? I'm very unfamiliar with both Java and Kotlin, especially how Star Projection `<*>` works and how it relates to this.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to use `ScheduledTask<*>` as a type. The `*` means the type is unknown to the compiler, but the compiler doesn't need to know the type to be able to call `cancel()` on it.

You do need to make the property nullable since it doesn't always exist. Then you can set it back to null when cancelled.

`newTask` probably should be private, and there's shorter lambda syntax you can use to create Runnables, as shown below.

```
companion object {

  val submitPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
  var taskHandle: ScheduledTask<*>? = null
  private val newTask = Runnable {
      foo()
    }
      
  fun onStatusChange(connected: Boolean) {
    if(connected) {
      taskHandle = submitPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(newTask, msUpdateRate, msUpdateRate, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    } else { 
      taskHandle?.cancel(true) // Cancel the task (if it exists)
      taskHandle = null
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass Callable instead of Runnable so the type will be known. If `foo` returns Unit (i.e. doesn't return any value), use `<Unit>` as the type.

```
companion object {

  val submitPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
  var taskHandle: ScheduledTask<Unit>? = null
  private val newTask = Callable {
      foo()
    }
      
  fun onStatusChange(connected: Boolean) {
    if(connected) {
      taskHandle = submitPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(newTask, msUpdateRate, msUpdateRate, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    } else { 
      taskHandle?.cancel(true) // Cancel the task (if it exists)
      taskHandle = null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer!